# Support for -march=native in clang 15 on m1 pro cpu

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, clang, apple-m1

As a part of trying to optimize the performance of a c++ project involving a lot of RNG and Eigen matrix/vector operations I've been trying out different compiler flags, such as -03, -mcpu=apple-m1 etc.

I've been told that clang 15 supports the -march=native flag. I however have been struggling quite a bit with uncovering where to acquire clang 15.

Currently I have installed clang 14 via "brew install llvm", and tried to set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm@14/bin/clang")
which, however keeps throwing the following compilation error:

"ld: library not found for -lSystem
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

N.B. MacBook Pro (14", 2021) w. Apple M1 Pro

Please let me know if you know a workaround or a good explanation for the error. :)

Comment: clang 15 is not released yet, unless you want a beta / RC version.

Comment: Apple's clang 13.1.6 has good support for Apple Silicon. I've seen info suggesting it supports Apple Silicon better than Clang 14.